# Replacing elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which is defined as follows:

```
mean=[0,1,3,6,4,5,nan,456,nan,5,3,7,nan]
```

How do i replace all the values having nan to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "nan" really is a [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), you can't use ordinary comparisons to find them, NaN is not equal to any other number or NaN. Yes, it's not equal to itself.

So, you have to use [`math.isnan()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) to do the checking:

```
mean2 = [0 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in mean]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `nan` is already a defined variable, then you can do:

```
>>> nan="nan"
>>> mean=[0,1,3,6,4,5,nan,456,nan,5,3,7,nan]
>>> print([0 if i==nan else i for i in mean])
[0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 456, 0, 5, 3, 7, 0]
```

For `NaN` referring `Not a Number`:

```
>>> import math
>>> mean=[0,1,3,6,4,5,float("NaN"),456,float("NaN"),5,3,7,float("NaN")]
>>> print([0 if math.isnan(i) else i for i in mean])
[0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 456, 0, 5, 3, 7, 0]
```